# get a row of sharepoint list using sharepoint web service

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list that has n numbers of columns.  I would like to get row #5 of the list for example using sharepoint web service.  I searched internet and found some code, but it is hard to understand the query syntax.  Can I not specify a single row of the list? Any suggestion?

Comment: If it is sharepoint 2010 you can use client object model.

Comment: Did any of the following suggestions help you?

Comment: I found something like this and it works:  query.InnerXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
                        "<Value Type=\"Counter\">" + rowNum + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is really not easy. I've created a JavaScript library called [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) that permits to do a SQL-like query.

The JavaScript code (after you have loaded jQuery and SharepointPlus) would be something like:

```
var row=5; // I assume that when you say "row #5", you mean the item with the ID = 5
$SP().list("Name of your list").get({fields:"NameField",where:"ID = "+row}, function(data) {
  if (data.length===0) alert("The item with ID = "+row+" doesn't exist!")
  else alert("NameField = "+data[0].getAttribute("NameField"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SPServices you can use the following code:

```
$(window).ready(function () {

GetItemsFromList();
});


function GetItemsFromList()
{
 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "MyTestList",
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Name' /></ViewFields>",
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>5</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
 // $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
 $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row,row").each(function() {
    var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "   " +  $(this).attr("ows_Name") +  "</li>";
    $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
    alert(liHtml);
  });
}
  });

}
```

In the above code I am getting items with id=5 or you can get all the items from the list and fetch the 5th row from the datatable.
You can get all the items from the list by changing the query to the following in the above code:

```
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Name' /></ViewFields>"
```

You can also use client object model. Following is the code using ECMA Script:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
function retrieveListItems()
{
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var siteColl = clientContext.get_site();
    var oList = siteColl.get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('MyTestList');  

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
   camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>5</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>");
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
{
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
var currentitemtitle = "";
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
{
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
   currentitemtitle = currentitemtitle + oListItem.get_item('Title') ;


} 


}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
{
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

In the above code I am getting item with id 5 from the list. You can also get all the items by changing the query as given above and then get the 5th row by iterating through the rows.

I hope this helps..